# Accounting cell type changes when read/write - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, numbers, accounting

I am reading some cells of type accounting into a Variant variable and then writing the variable in a new workbook. When I do this, the number formatting gets all mixed up.

I first read the cell from the first workbook with value **69,77 €** and cell format *Accounting*:

```
Dim tiendas As Variant
x=.Cells(1,1)
```

Then I create a new workbook and write the content of the variable into a cell:

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = x
```

If I don´t do anything else, the copied value looks like this **697.715** and has a cell format of *Number*.

Then I try changing the cell format before writing the value, i.e.:

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A1").Style = "Currency"    
wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = x
```

As a result I get **€  697.715,00** and cell type *Custom*.

I have tried inverting the order, i.e. first writing the value and then changing the style to "Currency". This results in exactly the same result.

I have also tried changing the format in the different way, specifically by using what appears in the custom formatting in Excel (and doubling the quotes inside the string):

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A1").NumberForma="_-* #.##0,00 €_-;-* #.##0,00 €_-;_-* "" - ""?? €_-;_-@_-"   
wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = x
```

The result in this case is **697715,000 €** and cell format *Custom*.

It seems that the original number format is not being read properly but I don´t know how to fix this.

Any ideas are very mucho welcome.

Thanks in advance!

NOTE: My number setting in Windows are "," as a decimal symbol and "." as thousands separator.

Comment: Maybe a misunderstanding here - when you read the cell's value with `x=.Cells(1,1)`, you're not reading the format at all, but the underlying value. If you want the format, you definitely have to apply it yourself, or copy it from the original cell.

Comment: Thanks BigBen. Wouldn´t the underlying value be 69,77 (without €)? If I write that value and then format it back to accounting, shouldn´t it work? Thanks!

Comment: What about just storing the `.NumberFormat` from `.Cells(1,1)` as a variable and then re-using that when writing the value?

Comment: Not sure how to store a format as a variable. But I tried .Cells(Destination).NumberFormat=Cells(Origin).NumberFormat...the result was: 697715 :S

Comment: The `.NumberFormat` is a `String`... so just read it into a `String`.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. I was actually storing the variable as String instead of Variant. Thanks for your support!